# Upper semi-continuity of log-concave functions

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory

A function $f:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow [0,\infty)$ is said to be log-concave if $\log  f$ is a concave function on the support of $f$.

I was reading this paper where the author said that upper semi-continuity of a log-concave function is really a technical issue, since one can modify $f$ on a set of measure 0 to make it upper semi-continuity and still log-concave.

Does anyone have any idea how this modification is done?

Comment: If $f$ never vanishes then it is continuous. Indeed, $g=\log(f)$ is concave, hence continuous, so $f$ is the exponential of a continuous function.

Comment: Can you please link the paper if you still have it? I am interested in reading it.